# Validate, Sign and Upload using different accounts

Tags: ios

I have developed an app for the client and the client wants to upload to the AppStore for the review. I want to validate and sign`iOS` app before I give it to the client.

***My question is***: Can I validate and sign the `iOS` app using account `user@example.com` whereas the client will use different account `client@example.com` to upload the app the AppStore.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

first of all I don't think this is right forum for this kinds of questions. Is it possible? Yes, you can change owner of an app (move app to another account) any time you want. If your client gives you permission, you can even upload app to client's account using developer license.